# Non-blocking writes to Java SocketChannel

Tags: java, sockets, socketchannel

If I obtain a `SocketChannel` that is set to the non-blocking mode, what happens when I write to the channel and the underlying socket buffer is full because the other side cannot keep up? Would the data be discarded or something to that effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `write()` method returns zero and the data stays in the `ByteBuffer`. At that point you should register the channel for `OP_WRITE`, remember the output buffer, return to the select loop. When the channel becomes writable, retry the write, and this time as long as it completes, i.e. doesn't return zero or less than the remaining bytes in the buffer to be written, deregister `OP_WRITE`.